# How to increase drop shadow opacity in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

With the drop shadow with this code:

```
func dropShadow(){
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}
```

I achieve this:

[image]

How to make the shadow more visible like below?

[image]

Comment: Silly idea, but have you thought of putting just another layer with the same drop shadow on top of it?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did but they rejected it in code review :) lol